# Not able to add Google native ads in my iOS swift app

Tags: ios, swift, admob, native

I have an iOS app in swift language. I have included Google AdMob ads in my app. I have implemented banner ads and interstitial ads but I am not able to generate the Ad ID for Native Ads. I have found an Ad Sense custom search native ads but I don't know for what purpose these ads are used. Can I use AdSense native ads in my mobile app. Please suggest me what to do and how to progress?

Comment: Hi 
From here you can implement native banner ads from google admob
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/admob-native-advanced-feed-ios/#0

Answer (score -1):

Below are the steps that I always follow whenever it comes to adding Google Admob Ads. Do take note that the example below will implement Google Admob in a table view.

1. Install Google Admob Ads via pod `pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'`
2. In `AppDelegate > didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, setup/configure Google Admob `GADMobileAds.configure(withApplicationID: Constant.googleAdmobAppID)`
3. Next, create a class for Google Admob Banner.

```swift
import Foundation
import GoogleMobileAds

class GoogleAdMobBanner: NSObject, GADBannerViewDelegate {

    unowned var sourceTableViewController: UITableViewController
    var adBannerView: GADBannerView

    init(sourceTableViewController: UITableViewController) {
        self.sourceTableViewController = sourceTableViewController
        adBannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait)

        super.init()

        adBannerView.adUnitID = Constant.googleAdmobBannerID
        adBannerView.delegate = self
        adBannerView.rootViewController = sourceTableViewController
    }

    // MARK:- Google Admob

    func adViewDidReceiveAd(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
        print("Banner loaded successfully")

        // Reposition the banner ad to create a slide up effect
        let translateTransform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -bannerView.bounds.size.height)
        bannerView.transform = translateTransform

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            bannerView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            self.sourceTableViewController.tableView.tableHeaderView = bannerView
        }
    }

    func adView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError) {
        print("Fail to receive ads")
        print(error)
    }

    func loadAdMob() {
        let request = GADRequest()
        request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID]

        adBannerView.load(request)
    }

}
```

4. Declare a lazy loaded admob banner in the desired class.

```swift
class MyController: UITableViewController {

    lazy var googleAdMobBanner: GoogleAdMobBanner = {
        return GoogleAdMobBanner(sourceTableViewController: self)
    }()

}
```

5. Lastly, load the Google Admob in `viewDidLoad`

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    googleAdMobBanner.loadAdMob()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! but this is for banner ads.Are you showing these ads between table view rows???I am looking for native ads to display in between table view rows..

Comment: @AadharMathur the example I showed above will seamlessly display the ads at the top of the table view